# How to write a script to check if a list of usernames exists automatically based on the ajax response from the webpage?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax

There's a webpage with a username text input field. The field is associated with a onchange event listener that checks if the username already exists and dispalys a text message adjacent to the input field telling whether the username exists or not in the website. The response is dynamically received through an AJAX request whenever the onchange event is triggered on the username input field.

Now, I have 100 usernames. I want to check if the username exists or not automatically through a script. Basically, each username has to be entered into the input field, an onchange event has to be manually triggered to that field, wait for ajax response from the server that tells whether the username exists or not and then iterate to the next username on the list.

How do I write a script to automate this? I had tried writing a javascript snippet to do it, but I am not able to fetch the ajax response and the field is always undefined.

```
document.getElementById("username").value = "user"
document.getElementById("username").onchange()
console.log(document.getElementById("result").innerText) # It logs undefined here
```

Only after this three statements get executed, the "result" field receives the response from the server.
If I execute `console.log(document.getElementById("result").innerText)` after this once again, it now prints the ajax response. I am trying this via the Chrome developers console.

Comment: You should be able to copy the code that normally runs in the `change` event listener, and execute it in a loop.

Comment: @Barmar have updated the question, can you check it once?

Comment: AJAX is asynchronous, you're not waiting for the result.

Comment: You need to find the actual code that normally runs during the change event. Then you have to write your own code that sends the same kind of AJAX request and processes the response itself, because the original code isn't designed to be used as an API.

Comment: @Barmar How to know when the ajax response is received from the server? I tried mimcking a wait function after the onchange trigger and before console logging the result, but still it outputs undefined? Any other hacky way to automate this?

Comment: You can't, that's why you need to write your own `$.ajax()` call. The `success:` function will receive the response.